# Python script to catch failed commands or warnings messages

Tags: python, networking, cisco

I have a little script that telnets into a network switch and executes commands.  It works fine but I need it stop and show an error message if any of the commands fail or network give a waning or something.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import telnetlib


HOST = "10.10.10.1"
user = "Test"
password = "TestPW"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("username: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
tn.read_until("password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")

n, match, previous_text = tn.expect([r'Login incorrect', r'\$'], 1)
if n == 0:
    print "Invalid Credentials"
    tn.close()
else:
    tn.write("Term len 0\n")
    #Reads data from commands.txt file and executes it line by line
    with open("commands.txt") as commands:
        singlecommand = commands.read()
        tn.write(singlecommand)
        print singlecommand
    #Need exception/error checking to catch fail commands or warnings.
    tn.write("exit\n")
    tn.write("y\n")
    print tn.read_all()
    tn.close()
```

I want the script to stop executing more commands after a fail command or a warning from CLI that something maybe wrong.  It already has the print function so it should display the error message and command that failed.

Here is a example of a failed command:

> % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Here is an example warning message:

> %Warning:

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Try/Except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) statements.

They're related to the [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) part of the Python docs.

**Example:**

```
try:
    wrong_sum = "a" + 2
except ValueError:
    print "You got a Value Error"
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the message based on key word appeared in failed command, then raise the exception.
for example:

```
try:
     if '%Warning' == message[:8]:
          raise Exception('Test')
except Exception:
     print message
```